# Generic type guard including primitives

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a generic type guard, I've read answers that led me to this solution:

```
function typeGuard<T>(o, constructor: { new(...args: any[]): T }): o is T {
    return o instanceof constructor;
}
```

This works for any class that has a constructor, e.g.:

```
class b {
    k: number;

    constructor(k: number) {
        this.k = k;
    }
}
console.log(typeGuard(new b(5), b));
```

I'm having trouble getting this to work for something like:

```
console.log(typeGuard(5, number));
```

or

```
console.log(typeGuard<number>(5));
```

I've tried this:

```
type prim = "string" | "number" | "boolean"; // or without quotes
function typeGuard<T>(o, constructor: { new(...args: any[]): T }): o is T;
function typeGuard<T extends prim>(o): o is T;
function typeGuard<T>(o, constructor?): o is T {
    if (constructor) {
        return o instanceof constructor;
    }
return typeof o ==="string";
}
```

But this implementation doesn't let me look into what T is and do something like `if typeof o === T` or something like that.

Is there a way to implement this? Theoretically I'd like to pass `string` as the `constructor` argument like `typeGuard(5, string)` but this would require `constructor`s type to be: `{ new(...args: any[]): T } | Type<string> | Type<number> | Type<boolean>` but I don't know how to implement this in typescript.

Example of use:

```
class firstClass {
    n: number;
    constructor(n: number) {
        this.n = n;
    }
}

class secondClass {
    id: Date;
    constructor(d: Date) {
        this.id = d;
    }
}

function toConsole(a): void {
    if (typeGuard(a, firstClass)) {
        console.log(a.n);
    } else if (typeGuard(a, secondClass)) {
        console.log(a.id);
    } else if (typeGuard(a, string)) {
        console.log(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make the `constructor` argument either a constructor or (say) a string literal corresponding to `"string"`, `"number"`, `"boolean"`, etc.  But why do you want this as a function instead of just using `instanceof` inline?  A use case might help motivate a more appropriate answer.

Comment: `instanceof` works for types with a constructor - you're right that my first implementation merely wraps an `instanceof` call. I've tried to wrap it in a function call to extend it to include primitive types.

Comment: I've added an example of how I wish to use the type guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure what the real need is for this to be a single function, but let's see what we can do.  You need to provide, at runtime, a value for the function to use to determine if you're checking for a string, number, or something else.

Let's say that the second argument to `typeGuard()` is called `sentinel`, of type `Sentinel`, which can either be a constructor, or one of the string values corresponding to what `typeof` gives you.

```
type TypeofMap = {
  string: string,
  number: number,
  boolean: boolean
}
type Sentinel = (new (...args: any[]) => any) | keyof TypeofMap;
```

Then, given a value of a type that extends `Sentinel`, the type you're guarding is related to the type of `Sentinel` via the following [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types):

```
type GuardedType<T extends Sentinel> = T extends new (...args: any[]) => infer U ? 
  U : T extends keyof TypeofMap ? TypeofMap[T] : never;
```

And you can implement `typeGuard()` like this:

```
function typeGuard<T extends Sentinel>(value: any, sentinel: T): value is GuardedType<T> {
  // assign to Sentinel instead of generic T to allow type guarding†
  const concreteSentinel: Sentinel = sentinel;
  if (typeof concreteSentinel === "string") {
    return typeof value === concreteSentinel;
  } else {
    return value instanceof concreteSentinel;
  }
}
```

<sub>(† See [Microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) for the reason for `concreteSentinel`)</sub>

And here's how you'd use it:

```
declare const thing: string | number | RegExp;
if (typeGuard(thing, "string")) {
  console.log(thing.charAt(0));
} else if (typeGuard(thing, RegExp)) {
  console.log(thing.flags);
} else {
  console.log(thing.toFixed(0));
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: This goes way above my knowledge of Typescript, so I'm glad I asked - I wouldn't have gotten there any time soon. This accomplishes what I've tried to do, thanks!

Comment: @jcalz how would you extend this to allow any number of arguments in the `typeGuard`fn? for example: `typeGuard(thing, 'a', 'b')`

Comment: I'd like to use something like this to check if `thing` is an object that has any number of defined keys that can also be type checked. eg. `thing = { a: 'a', b: 2 }`

Comment: Maybe you want something like the type guard composition code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59483318/2887218)?  `const thingChecker = G.gObject({ a: G.gString, b: G.gNumber });`

Comment: Unfortunately, the type narrowing issue has been closed but it still persists in this case, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995#issuecomment-886995095) is my comment about it which also has a link to TS playground with a reproduction.