# Typescript check object by type or interface at runtime with typeguards in 2020+

Tags: typescript

Most of the time for me, dynamic check is needed for verification of fetch response. And i was thinking, can this be done with user defined typeguard in a generic way for any type of object with multiple props and additional checks, so it can be used something like:

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=43#code/PTAEF5K6c0GcAWBDATgUwCanQDwA4D2qALlhLJVAFAkCe%206oA6qgJZmoSgDe1ooAHbIAtugBcCEu0EBzfqGSyJQgK4iARulTUAvtVoMmAIUKEA1tz4C2mSYPVadA4WMnxpbOQpJL47zzkAbQBdUAAfNQAbKIUAd3ZOfxZE7VC9AxBQADNVQQBjEjZCQVASQlB8xHR8y0INACsaklA4jkRQEVUoovwopnxUQnx4UGVBbWQohBRGABoyisFCFswKjlANOlAUQUxqXIKiktBCbIAVIwAec4A%20AAp6hslkQToASkkn0DZR894FGxsqB7gBCJ7vUAYEiqVClbJTeDoADcCgUoCyiEIcUWAH50dDYaVpKomFliDlEUwMtQslR6aBVEjsK9sJh0NkvOQvJVCCIiBNBCRRvSqAc8oViqVfqYLI9Gi83p9To0fqNZZZrD9gWCzpdGFcNQ8IZDCXDKVEkRjgFUauYvLIchSkMhGIo9gg2Pz%20mUjPADAIsrb7XInVx4Ix8kC2PlQAA3Kak0asqGvZT%20mw6p4AOlsoCuoAAjKb0DDzQjLdTMyCcwkONpRgAyRsqhrZutJbPwPnoe73XiKZSgXSgd7gW6DpgFgCsEUiSiYE8L04ADO8S2X4VTQAGoaWiWVUKSaQJqPkSh5NmZLOAATY7EW5gpXCoAOQAQQTcgbr6fAl8sjJEEr4iGgcboFEv6gK%20hyviEf6tKkqBAbwL6SK%20ACyyC4FBC6SAATNOugLDwaHQVhOELHhoCEboIQ0uegjdv02ZRIQsj3DK173Bo17rtah6kqcXAVkiQA).

[Here is an example with sample object, but i want a function without it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442746/check-if-object-correctly-implements-interface)

```
// ================= shared exported =================
type Writer = {
  name: string
  age: number
}

type Book = {
  id: number
  name: string
  tags: string[] | null
  writers: Writer[]
}

// function to check object with multiple props general shape, to not do it by hand
function ofType<T>(obj: any): obj is T {
  if (!obj) return false;

   // how to?
   return true // or false 
}

// ================= used and defined in components =================
function isBook(obj: any): obj is Book {
  if (!ofType<Book>(obj)) return false //checking for shape and simple types

  // cheking for specific values and ranges
  if (obj.id < 1) return false 
  if (obj.writers && obj.writers.some(( { age } )=> age < 5 || age > 150)) return false 

  return true
}


const book = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Avangers',
  tags: ['marvel', 'fun'],
  writers: [ {name: 'Max', age: 25}, {name: 'Max', age: 25}]
}

console.log(isBook(book)) // true or false
```

Comment: As i found in this issue, there seems no easy way as of now :( https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3628

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is [erased](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when compiled to JavaScript.  That implies any effort to use the standard `tsc` compiler by itself to generate runtime type guards from `type` or `interface` definitions will not succeed; there's nothing of these definitions left at runtime for you to use. So `ofType<T>()` cannot be implemented.

So what *can* you do?

---

If you're willing to use some other compilation step in your build system, you can write or use a transformer that makes type guards for you from these definitions before they are erased.  For example, [`typescript-is`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-is) will do this.

---

Or you could use `class` definitions instead; this makes checking easy at runtime (just use `instanceof`) but the hard part is deserializing JSON into a class instance and catching errors upon deserialization without writing this yourself manually.   All this does is move your problem from implementing `ofType<Book>(someObj)` to implementing `myDeserializerFunction(Book, someObj)` where `Book` is a class constructor.

Here at least you can use [decorators](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorators) and [class metadata](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata) to generate the code needed for programmatic deserialization.  You can write this yourself, or use an existing library such as [`json2typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2typescript).

---

Finally, you might decide to start with the type guards and let TypeScript *infer* your `type` definitions from them.  That is, instead of defining `Book` and hoping to get a type guard `bookGuard()` from it, you write the type guard `bookGuard()` and define `Book` in terms of `typeof bookGuard`.

This type guard could be built by composing existing simpler type guards together, so it looks more like a declarative type definition than a data-checking function.  You can write this yourself, or use an existing library such as [`io-ts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/io-ts) or [`zod`](https://zod.dev/).

For this approach, it's instructive to look at how one might write such a library.  Here's one possible implementation:

```
export type Guard<T> = (x: any) => x is T;
export type Guarded<T extends Guard<any>> = T extends Guard<infer V> ? V : never;
const primitiveGuard = <T>(typeOf: string) => (x: any): x is T => typeof x === typeOf;
export const gString = primitiveGuard<string>("string");
export const gNumber = primitiveGuard<number>("number");
export const gBoolean = primitiveGuard<boolean>("boolean");
export const gNull = (x: any): x is null => x === null;
export const gObject =
    <T extends object>(propGuardObj: { [K in keyof T]: Guard<T[K]> }) =>
        (x: any): x is T => typeof x === "object" && x !== null &&
            (Object.keys(propGuardObj) as Array<keyof T>).
                every(k => (k in x) && propGuardObj[k](x[k]));
export const gArray =
    <T>(elemGuard: Guard<T>) => (x: any): x is Array<T> => Array.isArray(x) &&
        x.every(el => elemGuard(el));
export const gUnion = <T, U>(tGuard: Guard<T>, uGuard: Guard<U>) =>
    (x: any): x is T | U => tGuard(x) || uGuard(x);
```

Here we are exporting a few type guards and functions which compose existing type guards.  The `gString()`, `gNumber()`, `gBoolean()`, and `gNull()` functions are just type guards, while `gObject()`, `gArray()`, and `gUnion()` take existing type guards to make new type guards out of them.  You can see how `gObject()` takes an object full of type guard properties and makes a new type guard where each property is checked against the corresponding guard.  You could add other composition functions like `gIntersection()` or `gPartial()`, but the ones here are enough for your example.

Now your `Book` and `Writer` definitions look like this (assume the above has been imported as namespace `G`):

```
const _gWriter = G.gObject({
    name: G.gString,
    age: G.gNumber,
});
interface Writer extends G.Guarded<typeof _gWriter> { }
const gWriter: G.Guard<Writer> = _gWriter;

const _gBook = G.gObject({
    id: G.gNumber,
    name: G.gString,
    tags: G.gUnion(G.gArray(G.gString), G.gNull),
    writers: G.gArray(gWriter)
})
interface Book extends G.Guarded<typeof _gBook> { }
const gBook: G.Guard<Book> = _gBook;
```

If you squint at that you'll see that it's analogous to your example `Writer` and `Book` definitions.  But in our case the fundamental objects are type guards `gWriter` and `gBook` and the types `Writer` and `Book` are derived from them.  And then you can use `gBook` directly instead of the non-existent `ofType<Book>()`:

```
const book = JSON.parse('{"id":1,"name":"Avangers","tags":["marvel","fun"],' +
    '"writers":[{"name":"Max","age":25},{"name":"Max","age":25}]}');

if (gBook(book)) {
    console.log(book.name.toUpperCase() + "!"); // AVANGERS!
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBxJBvAsAKCXpEAHjAPYBOALkhQJ4zIoCuIZAJgDwAqAfEgLxIAFIQBcSEMBoBKfr0JIAllCScA3DnwFi5KrXqpmbCB05aKEYK2VMWHCTW68BpoucvXDHBcABmEMkgAarwA-EFIYsAQAG7+6rj48CTAUFQwZApgChQKsTZs-Ehc3IJ6EADyPmKpGcAA5jJ8vMJi9lJi8koqstR0ECQ+SPJ8I730lfGaRKSUSEkpVHUAyhS1dYXpmdm5EPkcNd51JQBEB-XHUqpIGvjTOnPJqUh1AHKMYABG-hsZWTl5nnYwHeXzIJ2Bn38F0mt20s3mTzqACESCQADYQCQ-Lb-XaAj6ojESE4E9GY4DQm54O7wx6LN5otGFFriSTtIaKZTAxk9YajblomHUuFUBGLcofABWEHgVD4VM0RRchDcViQJClMooJXSJBgewlkrE6CQAG0ANKKYBIADWEBoAxUAF0xHsuBanbwAL6NbgKxX4FltDqc7pNMb9QZ8gTHDXS2XHJAAMiTHIAhPzGDyU-6A4rBIatQA6O00KCCXX6zyGmQgZQAQTIZBANHYpcdPCkRdzebzMX8NEENp6Q6tQxkKaQlYNUtNNqdwjnTqklwVNNFdOejebNH4PaVJQgGLAe1dgM7I9ErOkIa625bxR695oRaUz+EE6T+80hCL-bIg5Hj0R4QCeniCEeK5CloMwbgszwAKrAAoySFFwAA0SAISUFCngYtjFJhjB4W62G+vuQZsreyimAAPlhPS4eBhAyLR9HEcxq7YF6OC8dgYpIAA+nUADqGTmAEAgoEWdSFrKghYAkeCgJAroySsazoQqIB1BAamvCC-hadxXHeBJPgIMgYnZN8rgWGq0l7MY7BlI6wnWRJvAmjx-GbqJ4n+Gpboef4ThCf5NlkPEOACcJKIkMOUkyXJFAKQqCisPpbyQmQxmaCpemoOpqyHHl+AUDpUD6UhKHAII0l1O+DUaYcUiYQ1DJom1CoAO4BWQVVFY1TYtoIEUSVIOA+jgZn+BZiBIPFw52e4RVORwrmDHFqI2l5SA+QJyI7UFgJLWF20JdF2B8QA9Dd-AjI9T3PaMjBQMYrKsEgrAQD43gfd4DxgKQUTABQygvZDT04D4jDALKtWcktghxq0VHqlKoZLRg6WDIIaZHQlKNSiuSBkBAFCMGQ1oWWi71IHd8AABYyjahxID45BIFATMgPoEhfVAmQwBiEZQHxmh3XMLNs-UHNc7AMoKH98BINEIBoow0CfWTEi6eLSmKHjcavl97BIAAjDI5OU9THMa+9uNCCbfWRcok4u-1UBFlAJCQIICniLp+2+kHyDmwArEgbFh0gvAWxHAAMpM21TNMOxAEv4KndurFrU18QJpKJUgABSSzlC8RZwANECCAA5OgxwZccIgW+hxwFa3xz1ur9T+FAxwdxVdSDyIprHGALCxGiQ-HLDFJOuh9dIAA1Aq9fHK7Elj6aTddyIxwALIgIQc86RArcAEwR166H7+Al+HyfZ8dxf1+306Xr11xM144TNpBDF1JopTQCIyRFjRCQOoQCdpFgKkWCgJAEIwHoGQAAwnWOuMhV5IGOGmaEDN7r1kCPWF4KAACiAAlJYaYC7XQYeAjEkDoGCCUMjYBMgpZ52QFzWmjsGE4AAYIAUk1BHYCAA)

Answer (score 36):

There are actually a number of modules which attempt to translate TypeScript type information into runtime information that can be used to validate data structures.

I'll attempt to list and compare the various solutions here. (ordered roughly by how effective/general-purpose I estimate them to be; yes, this is somewhat subjective!)

**Core features**: (marked with ✔️yes, ❌no, ⚙️partial, ❔unknown)

> **<kbd>ts-base</kbd> TS base:** Standard TypeScript types are used as the basis for the type-metadata. (rather than vice-versa)
> **<kbd>class</kbd> Classes:** Can generate type-metadata for classes (based on shape, *not* instanceof), rather than just interfaces.
> **<kbd>func</kbd> Functions:** Can generate type-metadata for functions.
> **<kbd>guard</kbd> Type-guards:** Includes functions to validate runtime data against the type-metdata. (ie. type-guards)
> **<kbd>auto</kbd> Auto-check:** Can automatically generate invocations of the included type-guards.

### Solutions

#### [typescript-is](https://github.com/woutervh-/typescript-is)

> <kbd>**[GitHub](https://github.com/woutervh-/typescript-is): 500**</kbd>
> <kbd>**[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-is): 2,555**</kbd>
> (2020-09-30)
>
> **Core features:**
> <kbd>ts-base: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>[class](https://github.com/woutervh-/typescript-is/issues/20): ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>func: ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>guard: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>auto: ⚙️</kbd>
> **Note:** Auto-check marked as partial, since you can add decorators to class-methods (but not standalone functions) to have their argument types checked.

#### [typescript-json-schema](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema) (+ a [schema validator](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validators), eg. [ajv](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv))

> <kbd>**[GitHub](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema): 1,400**</kbd>
> <kbd>**[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-json-schema): 51,664**</kbd>
> (2020-09-30)
>
> **Core features:**
> <kbd>ts-base: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>class: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>func: ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>guard: ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>auto: ❌</kbd>
> **Pro:** Generates valid json-schemas, which have additional uses. (eg. can be used for data validation in [other languages](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validators))
> **Con:** Requires some manual work to write generated schemas to disk, package them to be available at runtime, and feed them to your selected JSON-schema validator.

#### [typescript-rtti](https://github.com/typescript-rtti/typescript-rtti)

> <kbd>**[GitHub](https://github.com/typescript-rtti/typescript-rtti): 54**</kbd>
> <kbd>**[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-rtti): 648**</kbd>
> (2022-03-09)
>
> **Core features:**
> <kbd>ts-base: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>class: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>func: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>guard: ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>auto: ❌</kbd>
> **Pro:** Provides rich metadata about the TypeScript types, that is usable for functionality beyond type-guards.

#### [tst-reflect](https://github.com/Hookyns/tst-reflect)

> <kbd>**[GitHub](https://github.com/Hookyns/tst-reflect): 77**</kbd>
> <kbd>**[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tst-reflect): 79**</kbd>
> (2022-03-09)
>
> **Core features:**
> <kbd>ts-base: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>class: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>func: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>guard: ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>auto: ❌</kbd>
> **Pro:** Provides rich metadata about the TypeScript types, that is usable for functionality beyond type-guards.

#### [ts-runtime](https://github.com/fabiandev/ts-runtime)

> <kbd>**[GitHub](https://github.com/fabiandev/ts-runtime): 313**</kbd>
> <kbd>**[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-runtime): 96**</kbd>
> (2020-09-30)
>
> **Core features:**
> <kbd>ts-base: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>class: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>func: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>guard: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>auto: ✔️</kbd>
> **Con:** Cannot currently be applied to only specific files or functions; it adds type-guard invocations throughout the project. (but [PRs appear welcomed](https://github.com/fabiandev/ts-runtime/issues/24))
> **Con:** Contains the note: "This package is still experimental and resulting code is not intended to be used in production. It is a proof of concept..."

#### [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) (alone)

> <kbd>**[GitHub](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts): 3,600**</kbd>
> <kbd>**[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/io-ts): 296,577**</kbd>
> (2020-09-30)
>
> **Core features:**
> <kbd>ts-base: ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>class: ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>func: ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>guard: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>auto: ❌</kbd>
> **Pro:** Doesn't require any typescript transformers, webpack plugins, or CLI commands to operate. (it uses "tricks" to infer the TS types from its custom type-definition structure)

#### [io-ts-transformer](https://github.com/awerlogus/io-ts-transformer) (extension for [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts))

> <kbd>**[GitHub](https://github.com/awerlogus/io-ts-transformer): 16**</kbd>
> <kbd>**[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/io-ts-transformer): 7**</kbd>
> (2020-09-30)
>
> **Core features:**
> <kbd>ts-base: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>[class](https://github.com/awerlogus/io-ts-transformer#io-ts-transformer-cant-do): ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>func: ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>guard: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>auto: ❌</kbd>

#### [ts-auto-guard](https://github.com/rhys-vdw/ts-auto-guard)

> <kbd>**[GitHub](https://github.com/rhys-vdw/ts-auto-guard): 134**</kbd>
> <kbd>**[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-auto-guard): 46**</kbd>
> (2020-09-30)
>
> **Core features:**
> <kbd>ts-base: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>class: ❔</kbd>
> <kbd>func: ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>guard: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>auto: ❌</kbd>
> **Con:** You must add a specific js-doc tag to each interface you want a type-guard generated for. (a hassle, and error prone)

#### [typeonly](https://github.com/paroi-tech/typeonly)

> <kbd>**[GitHub](https://github.com/paroi-tech/typeonly): 25**</kbd>
> <kbd>**[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeonly): 101**</kbd>
> (2020-09-30)
>
> **Core features:**
> <kbd>ts-base: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>class: ❔</kbd>
> <kbd>func: ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>guard: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>auto: ❌</kbd>
> **Con:** Cannot generate type-guards for generic types. (see [here](https://github.com/paroi-tech/typeonly/tree/master/typeonly#known-limitations))

#### [ts-type-checked](https://github.com/janjakubnanista/ts-type-checked)

> <kbd>**[GitHub](https://github.com/janjakubnanista/ts-type-checked): 13**</kbd>
> <kbd>**[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-type-checked): 3**</kbd>
> (2020-09-30)
>
> **Core features:**
> <kbd>ts-base: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>class: ❔</kbd>
> <kbd>func: ❌</kbd>
> <kbd>guard: ✔️</kbd>
> <kbd>auto: ❌</kbd>

**Not yet evaluated**: [ts-json-schema-generator](https://github.com/vega/ts-json-schema-generator), [typescript-to-json-schema](https://github.com/xiag-ag/typescript-to-json-schema), [gfx/typescript-rtti](https://github.com/gfx/typescript-rtti)
**Excluded** (no public repo): [typescript-runtime-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-runtime-types)

#### Disclaimer

I am not the creator or maintainer of any of the solutions listed. I created the list to help developers compare the various solutions, on a consistent set of criteria, while adding helpful information such as GitHub stars and NPM weekly downloads. (edits are welcome to periodically keep these values up-to-date -- though remember to change the last-update-time labels!)

For those with enough reputation, feel free to add additional solutions that you come across. (though please try to keep the text for your new entries consistent with the existing ones)

Comment: I have another solution to add: https://typescript-rtti.org.
It is a transformer-based solution that lets you use regular Typescript. Disclaimer: I am the author. I would edit your answer as you are asking, but your edit queue is full

Comment: @WilliamLahti Very cool! Definitely would be good to have in the list. Regarding the "your edit queue is full", I'm not sure exactly what that means / how to resolve it. I know that in the nav-bar there is a "suggested edits" panel (along with "First questions", "First answers", etc.), but that just shows me a generic list of suggested edits across the site, so I don't see why that would restrict someone's ability to suggest an edit for this particular post. Can you give the exact error message so I can google it?

Comment: Oh this is a global Stack overflow thing, users with 2k reputation can review suggested edits, you can only submit new suggested edits when that queue is not full. I don't have enough reputation for that though. The actual error is "Suggested edit queue is full"

Answer (score 1):

You can have the classes instead of types and check the `instanceOf`

Please check the example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/types-in-runtime

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 1):

## Here is how to do with TypeOnly

Install `typeonly` and `@typeonly/checker`:

```sh
# Used at build time
npm i -D typeonly

# Used at runtime
npm i @typeonly/checker
```

In the file `package.json`, add a command for `typeonly`. For example, assuming TypeScript is configured to output in a `dist/` directory:

```
    "build": "npm run typeonly && npm run tsc",
    "typeonly": "typeonly --bundle dist/book.to.json src/book.d.ts",
    "tsc": "tsc"
```

In your code, put the types in a separate definition file:

```
// src/book.d.ts

type Writer = {
  name: string
  age: number
}

type Book = {
  id: number
  name: string
  tags: string[] | null
  writers: Writer[]
}
```

Then, import your types and the checker in your code:

```
import { createChecker } from "@typeonly/checker";
import { Book } from "./book";

const checker = createChecker({
  bundle: require("./book.to.json")
});

function ofType(obj: any, typeName: "Book"): obj is Book
function ofType(obj: any, typeName: string): boolean {
  if (!obj) return false;
  return checker.check("./book", typeName, obj).valid
}

function isBook(obj: any): obj is Book {
  if (!ofType(obj, "Book")) return false //checking for shape and simple types

  // cheking for specific values and ranges
  if (obj.id < 1) return false 
  if (obj.writers && obj.writers.some(( { age } )=> age < 5 || age > 150)) return false 

  return true
}

const book = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Avangers',
  tags: ['marvel', 'fun'],
  writers: [ {name: 'Max', age: 25}, {name: 'Max', age: 25}]
}

console.log(isBook(book)) // true
```

Build with `npm run build`, then it should works.

See also: https://github.com/tomko-team/typeonly

Answer (score 1):

To complete the almost exhaustive [jcalz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59483318/8634147), in case of communicating with an external API, we may use generated TypeScript client: strongly typed, with ou without typeguard, depending of the generator / technology, for instance:

- [autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) with REST API using the OpenAPI Specification format
- [gRPC](https://grpc.io) and its experimental TypeScript support [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web#typescript-support)