# How to narrow object type with "in" and/or "hasOwnProperty"

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm writing a type guard for an interface, and I'm noticing that I cannot narrow `object` with `in` or `Object.hasOwnProperty.call` or `arg.hasOwnProperty`. Like this:

```js
interface Test {
    quest: string;
}

function isTest(arg: unknown): arg is Test {
    // this successfully narrows arg to "object"
    if (typeof(arg) !== "object" || arg === null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!Object.hasOwnProperty.call(arg, "quest")) {
        return false;
    }
    // at this point, I still cannot access arg.quest, because
    // "Property 'quest' does not exist on type 'object'". The same thing happens
    // if I invert the check and try to access it inside the conditional.

    if (!arg.hasOwnProperty("quest")) {
        return false;
    }
    // same problem, cannot access arg.quest because arg is still just "object"

    if (!("quest" in arg)) {
        return false;
    }
    // still the same problem.

    return true;
}
```

Because of this, I'm having to do a lot of type casting, which is annoying because the actual interface I want to check has many properties, not all of which are basic primitives. So basically, for each property I have to make something that looks like this:

```js
function isTest(arg: unknown): arg is Test {
    if (typeof(arg) !== "object" || arg === null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!Object.hasOwnProperty.call(arg, "quest")) {
        return false;
    }
    if (typeof((arg as {quest: unknown}).quest) !== "string") {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

... and generally, I feel like if I have to use `as` I've done something wrong. So how do I narrow `object` to an interface without writing a separate type guard for each property of the interface?

As to why I need such robust guards, it's because this is going in a server and I'm checking payloads sent to its API after being `JSON.parse`d so that I can do complex operations with them without worrying about finding out halfway through that the data is poorly structured.

Comment: read more: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10485, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732

Answer (score 7):

Although [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) is generally unsafe, I find it to be useful as the type of a parameter to a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isTest(arg: any): arg is Test {
  return (typeof arg === "object") && (arg !== null) &&
    ("quest" in arg) && (typeof arg.quest === "string");
}
```

The above compiles without error.  No, it is not actually enforcing safety inside the implementation, since `any` effectively shuts off type checking.  But as long as you verify that the implementation is doing the right thing, using `any` makes the compiler get out of your way so that the *callers* of `isTest()` can have type safety.

This is essentially the same thing as using `unknown` and [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), though, which you've said makes you feel like you've done something wrong.

But keep in mind that the implementations of user-defined type guard functions work this way no matter what.  The only thing the compiler verifies for you is that your return type is `boolean`.  It just *believes* you when you say that such a `boolean` result can be treated as the type guard represented by the type predicate `arg is Test`.  You could write this, for instance:

```
function isBadTest(arg: unknown): arg is Test {
  return Math.random() < 0.5; // no error
}
```

So while it makes sense that you'd like to get as much type safety as possible from the compiler, you should remember that implementing user-defined type guards shifts some of that burden onto you.  Adding an `as` or an `any` to the mix doesn't really give up much.

---

That being said, let me ignore the fact that you're writing your own type guard function and only pay attention to the issue where you have a value of type `unknown` and you're trying to get the compiler to see if it can be narrowed to `Test`, or at least to something with a `quest` property you can access.

The problem here is that TypeScript just doesn't have a built-in type guard that adds properties to the known type of an object type.  As you noted, you can't currently use `in` to do it (see [microsoft/TypeScript#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732)), and you can't use `hasOwnProperty()` to do it (see [microsoft/TypeScript#18282](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18282)).  If you want such a type guard, you have to write your own.  For example:

```
function hasProp<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey>(
  obj: T, 
  key: K
): obj is T & Record<K, any> {
  return key in obj;
}

function isTest2(arg: unknown): arg is Test {
  if (typeof arg !== "object") return false;
  if (arg === null) return false;
  if (!hasProp(arg, "quest")) return false; // use it here,
  if (typeof arg.quest !== "string") return false; // no error here
  return true;
}
```

---

Once you start going this route, though, and keeping in mind that your ultimate intent is to validate deserialized objects at runtime to see that they conform to TypeScript interfaces, I end up concluding that you'll want something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59483318/2887218).  In there I wrote a mini schema-validator that builds complex type guards from simpler ones.  Using that code, your `isTest()` is just:

```
const isTest3: G.Guard<Test> = G.gObject({ quest: G.gString });
```

where `G.gObject()` takes an object of property type guards and produces a type guard for an object with those properties, and `G.gString` is a type guard which verifies that its argument is a `string`.

So you might want to check out the other answer to avoid having to reimplement type guards for each interface.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwLABQyyAjgK6ZgBcyWUoA5gNyEC+hhMZICYwA9iGTAM6LAAo4UBjTggAngEpZ04RjSVchYlAhgyUIeLDyADhH4xkUhsgC8D5ACJ+AIwBWEXk8XIAZH7IkqoAhI4gZAA2kb4B2sRBTuSUTsJCNrGBxmYWVjYAdMlY9o5OdIw+LATsBJzcvAJCIgBCcAAmYmDBMsjcANYg-ADuIMrWqiIaxfhEyLr6hsgAsnBgABb5UHJt-AC24r4APMgADPkArEzIAPTXyIPI0FD8UGwctQRcPHyCyGtwGAACs9TIdUI8AB6QEBtdRuTy8AA0yAA0pDobDkMD+OYoCYURB5AA+cTwmioZF9Qk0FFjeFqND+ZAAJS8LzahxRyLkxK0s3mBiEVPkaWQ8KqNTq30aak6ACZujR+oMRmMbAzOnziMArNlzJZxrYwnZnPCvGAfHM9ILkPBIhgIFVtbr1Q4TRFor4BYs7Q6ncJdSF-kCQd1kUkKFgfF7rT64PbHfEdUETPq8tJCpHsMbnOUQAxLd6hL7E-zY0IwFAKBL3u8QHBdphTIgUABxLWQ0wvbCpttkKQc1BE+xBCGyBS+OzDiEa-0QCFdvHIXvIVv9qBtCCD9EQGHqNcDw48onDk3g+cY-frjmgGDQZAANWHAH5H8gaCAIAA3aD+hCCYpTHoXZgD4H8Dw3EcwRJXsAHkYBoPMGEnYdxDHawJxoGdJnBKdlxyA0ZzdfDzHgucF27ZB-xAYoGAAZUrRgRyA4AQLAiAII5JCSTKRj80qeJ50XbBqNogA5Mhdlce8TRYtjgHA69DgiKToB4lTpKgATZiEyjROwBhmn4fhIggORmOA0CFI4pTXGM0y5B4uyTLMkBtOIXSl305AGAk6IRzQ8clCwhkPUiexpxKd0okicjhKogCDNgjxzXseJiDBHc9zFFLeBJICcU45L3BoHBkAAbTRUBkGFA1UAAXRoTiwUq+rh1YFD0oSQKMOC5BsPUXDh17QiotNXKLX8QIZxzMKpq6hIgmK818mFDBxAK0wio8XwAWQABBKAtnkQ5aqsIdFHyBbFseH8oHkcQ+gioInuqiFMmQTbtvccq+nqtDfvqxRFDivTEp8w7jrS2YMqHcQIFM3ZOKapSLuenqeTGAaDqOuATqHZ7Ibx-IRCJh73vmmGEghfJv2gB6EeehGICR694ZiEHBIorzwYYABVEAZRNMFkT5mDkdXVGiWRMgJeasXOqpjHMP6jVkAAH2QPnnrATi0N8dXNdltn3prD5vJEToAGYmvyZrOlPVd8gYZbeHEMqimoJ36L42wOqqQhvPpE0VnWTZtj2A5DjOc5kFfHBPZoUONkBABJVh31wRPTT6PGnFYKpk3ES3KCt0kdt8GZiFElz8kifgGHL9xM0ofIwH4PnTFxABhAEIAOEGbjuWCUX2gBNNhHgTDsa9MuuG6blusDb-gADFgAhLdxDlYGrluZArfyABGAAWNggA)