# Is it possible to create a random object from an arbitrary class using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, reflection, metadata

I was intent on implementing a test helper that could work like this:

```
class MyClass {
    field1: string;
    field2: number;
}

const randomObject: MyClass = Magic.generateRandomObject(MyClass);
```

And then `randomObject` would have the fields field1 and field2 populated with values of the appropriate types.

However, I am not able to see how I could do that in TypeScript. Is it at all possible to have something like this in a language that in the end will be transpiled to JS? From what I have gathered, I could use reflect-metadata, but then I would have to only use classes that have fields annotated with some decorator that would populate the metadata, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't something built into TypeScript; the static type system is erased when TS code is compiled to JS.  If you want such metadata you'll need some other build step.  I'm not familiar enough with things like [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) or the libraries mentioned in [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480160/typescript-check-object-by-type-or-interface-at-runtime-with-typeguards-in-2020) to suggest anything in particular.  If you want a purely TypeScript answer then you might want to consider starting with magic and *generating* your `class`.

Comment: Like, look at [this](https://tsplay.dev/Bmx9GW); here I'm doing a pure TS solution to generate the constructors and the random instances.  If you're interested I could write it up as an answer; let me know.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the comment. It's interesting, but I assume that that approach wouldn't work for arbitrary classes, or would it? Cause as I said, I wanted to be able to generate random instances of any class, and looking at your solution that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: In that case the answer is just going to be "no, you can't do this", with possibly some pointers to libraries that do code transformation/generation as a build step.  I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "any class", though. Surely you have some sort of description of what kinds of fields you support, right?  I mean, are they all JSON-like? Or can there be function-valued properties?  You can probably get quite far with an approach like I showed, but you are generating your classes from a schema, not vice versa.

Comment: @jcalz What I want is to have a helper like I mentioned for TypeORM entities from a database. I do have control over the classes, so I could write classes-from-schemas versions of them only for the purpose of having this helper, but that seems like a very bothersome task. I guess my best option for this would be to just write one randomObject per entity and give up on trying to have a more generic solution. But thank you for your comments, they shed light onto things I was having issues understanding.