# How do I properly narrow a type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typeguards, octokit-js

I'm using *Octokit* which is a GitHub client. I'm trying to read the contents of a directory and the return type of `octokit.repos.getContent` is a type union that has many possible values.

I'm trying to narrow the return value of `getContent` to only one of those options, it looks like this:

```
"content-directory": {
    type: string;
    size: number;
    name: string;
    path: string;
    content?: string;
    sha: string;
    url: string;
    git_url: string | null;
    html_url: string | null;
    download_url: string | null;
    _links: {
        git: string | null;
        html: string | null;
        self: string;
    };
}[]
```

I created a `type` out of it:

```
type DirectoryItems = components["schemas"]["content-directory"];
```

and now I'm trying to use it in a type guard:

```
const { data } = await octokit.repos.getContent({
    // ...
});

if(data instanceof DirectoryItems) {

}
```

but it says

> 'DirectoryItems' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

How can I narrow the type of `data` to make sure that it is indeed an array of "content-directory" items?

Comment: TypeScript's type system disappears at runtime; there's no `DirectoryItems` to check.  If you want runtime type checking you have to do the work yourself, as mentioned in the question this duplicates.  Good luck!

Comment: Translating the answer there here yields [this](https://tsplay.dev/1WGDKw).

Comment: It is a bit hard to read. What should I look for in there?

Comment: In where, the code?  The answers to the other question talk about possible ways to approach runtime type guards.  One possible approach is to write composable type guards and derive compile-time types from them (rather than the other way around, which is not possible without compiler extensions).  The linked code above does this for `DirectoryItems` (or `Array<DirectoryItem>`).  If you compare [here](https://tsplay.dev/jwgy9m) and squint you can see how the type guards are composed in a way that mimics declaring a type like `DirectoryItem`.

Comment: This is just too complex and unreadable to be used in production code.

Comment: Okeydokey, then perhaps you want one of the many other suggestions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59483318/2887218) or the other answers to that question.

Comment: Well, probably, thanks!