# How to console.log typescript type

Tags: typescript

I know that typescript type is not runtime variable. But is there any workaround how to print type name and variables?

```
type TestDto = {
    active: number;  
    user_name: string;
};
```

```
console.log(TestDto);
```

throw  `only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

I would like to create object property based on TS type. I would like to create JS object with property active and `user_name` with some default values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript check object by type or interface at runtime with typeguards in 2020+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480160/typescript-check-object-by-type-or-interface-at-runtime-with-typeguards-in-2020)

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to create object property based on TS type. I would like to create JS object with property `active` and `user_name` with some default values.

Your better option than creating an object based on a type to do *the opposite* and create the type based on an object. This not only gives you something concrete you can use at runtime, it can also serve as the defaults for the properties:

```typescript
const DefaultTestDto = {
    active: -1,
    user_name: "",
}

type TestDto = typeof DefaultTestDto;


const newDto1: TestDto = {...DefaultTestDto};
newDto1.user_name = "Fred";
//or
const newDto2: TestDto = Object.assign({}, DefaultTestDto, {user_name: "Barney"});

console.log(newDto1); // { "active": -1, "user_name": "Fred" } 
console.log(newDto2); // { "active": -1, "user_name": "Barney" }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgUwGYEMCuAbKAVB05QgwC8MA3gLABQMtMKwUAlgG4IBcMAtAIwA01OjDQQEAJwD6YFAFsOMAEQKBVAL7VqUAJ4AHBDFz5CJGNr0gk8ZOiyGoBEAG4NVaqEiwwCAO4OenOwcTMgA6MMRUTBw8e0JVZyovX0IeEJFxKVl9UgUAMTEEABMFBIB6UpAxN3BoGCSHACYAmKDSAHkAIwArBEYQlAgIJgBzMAAKMlU+K0jbFsJpsnTJaTlOBQAhFDEvLQVVAEoE6sgQDAQQjBBhsfqUo5hy8kUGZjYFTl5phWXMuQ-FPkigoYKoYCcIGcLlcbncQA0Hk8yC9GKwEACvopfqt0estjsEHtQTAgA)

Answer (score 4):

As you wrote, types are removed before execution.
If you want to create an object based on a type, classes are fine for that.
Or most IDE tools show you the structure of types when you hover over them if that's your purpose.