# Pick key-value pairs only when they exist

Tags: typescript

Given an object of `any` type, I'd like to construct another object of a defined type. e.g.

```
type P {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

In order to have a safe transformation, I want to convert it assuming the original object contains fewer or unexpected key-value pairs.

```
let object: any = { a: '1', c: 'unexpected' };
```

In this case, it makes more sense to have the new object with `Partial<P>` type, but I'm not sure how to construct it. The only approach I can think of is to have some complicated object assignments:

```
let p: Partial<P> = {
  ...(object.a ? { a: object.a } : {}),
  ...(object.b ? { b: object.b } : {})
}
```

Are there any better approaches to make the code cleaner (such as lodash utility function)?

Comment: How do you know that the `a` property, if it exists, is of type `string`?

Comment: It's a good question. Not sure but Is it possible to have something like `typeof ... === 'string'`?

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvYBQm) or something like it, but I don't know what you consider "clean" in order to answer the question.  Could you elaborate on what your criteria are?

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, that helps a lot. I'm just not sure if there is a simpler method call to handle similar problems (especially if type `P` has more keys)

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59480160/2887218) then?  There are answers in there with different methods for trying to make validators for types.  But there's no built-in "simple" method; if you have a bunch of keys of type `string` then you can add them to that array literal.  If you have a bunch of keys of arbitrary types, then you need to start building or using some sort of schema or some other build step; interfaces and types don't exist at runtime.

Comment: Like, you can start building general-purpose transformers like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4y3aw), or you could try to look for existing tools.  Keep in mind that the latter is usually considered out of scope for Stack Overflow.  Let me know if you want me to write this up as an answer, or if I'm missing something about your issue.