# Typescript does not throw error when casting unknown object with non-nullable property but with null as value

Tags: typescript, object, casting

So, I'm receiving a data from an external API using Typescript. This data is an Json Object that its not controlled by me (I'm just getting the data via http request).

The problem is, I have a model with an expected data, but sometimes, this API send data that is null, but should not be null in my side.
This happens for a lot of reasons, mostly because of bugs in their sides.

So as an example, I have this as an response:

```
const response = {
   id: 'this-is-an-id',
   name: 'this-is-a-name',
} //Imagine that I got this via an HTTP request
```

Then what I do, I cast this to my model in typescript:

```
interface User {
   id: string,
   name: string,
   email: string
}

const user = response as User;
```

The problem is, the code works and I get an user with an empty email property. And, according with the model, this shouldn't be possible.

I know that I could check is the property is there, then throw an exception, but I have a bunch of models, some a bit large and complex, and I don't want to write scripts to check if properties are there after casting it.

Has any other way to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is to validate the returned JSON against a JSON schema.

See [Typescript check object by type or interface at runtime with typeguards in 2020+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480160/typescript-check-object-by-type-or-interface-at-runtime-with-typeguards-in-2020/64136285#64136285) for some ideas about how to go about this.