# Are type predicates fragile? How to be always sure unknown matches a given type? Typescript

Tags: typescript, api, types, predicate, narrowing

Can we guarantee that in a type predicates all the needed checks are done, in order to safely infer that an unknown value matches a complex type?

**Example**:

Fetching some data from an API endpoint, e.g. `fetch("www.carworld.com/api/veichles-stats/truck-123", options)`.

The response is some stringified JSON of type `any`/`unknown`.

```js
const data: unknown = JSON.parse(respnse);
```

Luckily we have the API types from an **npm** package, and we can expect the data to be of the known type `TruckStats`:

```js
{
   name: "AreoTruck2019-Cruiser",
   speed: 300,
   weight: 9000,
   engine: {
       turbo: false,
       efficiency: 0.7
   }
}
```

We could cast the type, but this gives no guaranties that the API response **actually** matches the `TruckStats` type.

```js
const data: TruckStats = JSON.parse(respnse) as TruckStats
```

Next we could create a **type predicates** in which I have to manually create all the checks for all the properties described in the type (tedious).

```js
function isTruckStats(data: unkown): data is TruckStats{
  if(typeof data !== "object") return false;
  if(typeof data.name !== "string") return false;
  ...
  return true;
}
```

BUT, even doing that, what if the API and the type `TruckStats` changes (e.g. after a package update)? The Type predicates would suddenly it would start lying to me?

How to make sure that an unknown always matches a given type (so if they doesn't we get an error or a lint warning)?

I am aware that solutions like [typescript-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-is) and [ts-type-checked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-type-checked) exist. But they are *typescript transformers* and using them is not always a given (e.g. your bundler do not support them).

Comment: If the `TruckStats` type is not provided by the same code with the type guard function, then sure, you could run into problems.  The general approaches to runtime type guards are presented in the answers to the linked question.  Perhaps instead of using `TruckStats`, you use a `MyTruckStats` type defined by you with your type guard.  If `MyTruckStats` is structurally compatible with `TruckStats`, everything is fine.  If not, you will get an error somewhere when you pass a `MyTruckStats` somewhere a `TruckStats` is expected. This will prompt you to fix something.

Comment: You could even use something like the `Guard` functionality in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59483318/2887218) to generate `MyTruckStats` from the type guard.  Like [this example](https://tsplay.dev/wRGeQN).  If you uncomment the extra property in `engine`, you'll see an error later in your code with `MyTruckStats` not having the right subproperty