# Typescript: Generic Type Guard for Interface Detection at Runtime

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

**Complete Re-Edit**

I have a variety of classes, using a common base class and implementing common interfaces, that are instantiated at run-time based on config files. Because they are dynamically created, by default there is no intellisense/auto-complete unless I use a type guard. Right now I am tagging the classes using a `_interfaces` prop. As a contrived example...

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    _interfaces: any[] = []
}

interface A {
    propA: string
    funcA: (arg1: number) => void
}

interface B {
    propB: string
    funcB: (arg1: string) => void
}

class ExampleClass extends BaseClass implements A, B {
    propA = 'someValue'
    funcA(arg1: number){
        console.log('do a thing')
    }
    propB = 'anotherValue'
    funcB(arg1: string){
        console.log('do another thing')
    }
    _interfaces = ['A', 'B']
}

let myExampleClass = new ExampleClass() //this part is done dynamically at runtime
```

The runtime check in the type guard is simple, but actually typing the check for intellisense/auto-complete purposes is proving to be tricky.

I have a complicated version of this that works, but I am not fond of it. Currently am using a "type of types" and a few overly complicated types from [here](https://www.roryba.in/programming/2019/10/12/flattening-typescript-union-types.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type). There is a playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/PTDGHsFsAcBsEtQEMAuBTAJgAhQT2mgFB4FYCqAdvOBQCrgCSF6ATgM5qgrUUA8ZAPiwBeLAAoyWNAA90FDGyxIKuQliwB+cQGsAXOQCUIoQDdw8DGqz6KaE2hZGZcheLF6s8CgDMHWBkbCpuYYBlZaDFY2dg4A3ISEIMrgKAAWfhAwCMjo2CRE+VgAYrCocpQ8vLRCogDeVgDaANKeFFjaaLjg3uRUNPRMrBxcldUAuvotzmjyih1dPbSaVrTNY1KyM67KuA3rWqtNY1FYh+vTs1jgAEYAVpwomsWlKOV9fGcCJ2cnFf2MzAcw24NCqAjWhAAvgkQGk0FhQABXFgsGaPfIAc0RSBYlm8iIoIxonjYZDYXgxgwc3iQoDQbF4Kw2LkUAEEUUhcLx5t1-ICWDS6QAZeBsFACAA0Vimm0uAAVENpeFSBbS0CKxRLTg0KIjINcHGMvupjeIvNBESh9DstfM2PpaAZ9ObLSTnmUZn8+Fgmg0eT0jkJ6lZ1LA0I9UWxEbBHqI7QA6GIsXBiMQmJCwRFoAxBerqfP51EoZFtF0oDTxgD6XlYgvp8a8oEzGHpaYzWbCBchncL4ZLWEj0ZQUISNepaqwrKwefz0BY4GgrP0YpYFJDWHxhKX4hxGIAjDY9QbHEEzBYR4Qx6q6VgAELT9dzhe35coVcUDHrzegF87lj7193wxHMBDPSxoWIfB4RVOsNVjB8C23Vl11-W8LzDR4aQ6Wh6Xg2oIPgbwxFFMkKRgtU2DELC0BwzUsAaAByVkGK1BjbwYsYDAMGd1BAMdYAQDgKA4LAAHdwBYbQ2AAQihIA), but it is not for the faint of heart

I could have upwards of 10 interfaces or more applied to some classes so checking for specific properties isn't really scalable here.

Is there a simpler, more generic way, to get run-time detection of interfaces and get intellisense/auto-complete from a type guard?

**Updated**

Made a simpler version based on @jcalz comments and other posts using his `Intersectprops`. Playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-IAOUA9oagFzIDOYUoA5rgcjAK4gKXIAUcUDAIxUQbALYAjaAEpkAXgB8yAG4lgAE1wBfXLlCRYiFACFMzAsTLGqteiCZ4C7Ttd78hNuo1mKVazTg6OHrg0PBIyADCZo74loSRVBIkJAA2EHAg5vjOCIluAsLIyWkZID5KqhraujhgAJ6EKACSoYZIADLAtPIxLNyo2ciuxjXBdY0oAKrU0AAiEDCgEOpdPXJ9BPmRY7gNTcitBrMIYAAKpITUADwAKgA0yADSyBAAHpAg6tTIANYQ9RIMGQtyUGwwyAA2mdkKBngBdAC0AH4qDw3lRbtD4RU-BpkFpIU94a8PhAvtQhjx0VRQDBoIdcVV1LJkYdkCIIMpoABuWq5MDAEggZAMNj8dR3Umfb7IEgSABWEFOvSOYSMazACh40ghQxYUAgYDYUBF1xe7xlP3+gOBoJ48oVVEy9UeNuoVCekPhj0gtAotkYvQA5AB9fTqpDUYPSKiO2E-NVQE7nS43B7PMEKbCxFh59JgZCG6hsVKFjbugB0XOg9WpyjgqTYEGkihzeY7+aNyFSJAQjd6juRlchfrA8MroAQTfUEGoPAbTZb+s7BqNJpFvf7qRXHa0sgIu6L69Nx5LZaPQRYQVwBeQY96GC0yAA9C-aJl1HCYCQoMh1PUIBwGIwDbqk9TIAghpwJA6iQakcDUJS4xvkBgrcqK4pQHBADuwBgAAFv+ixwKWYA-D+f4AAZJuEECalR96TMgn7IFR4ZtHR1CMYh95zoW8R6MCPBihKOo8GO9yQsGqDBo8wbGMGOKyO2BBjpWuSoDwgjSEM6nxKglZgCQUyEE0UCRIhEA6np-EaRwCCjIEtRvmwsx-rOSwgCsmESkJvCidh1wzPMizLKs3RauJklQsGkRKfJoZuaFXkrDGuq2bQ9mcJEElQM2um5vplzoG+0CkFAuw4EAA). I still don't quite follow how the `Intersectprops` type works though.

Comment: The code here is pretty complicated/confusing if the question is about how to write a curried type guard function.  Using `K` for a non-keylike type parameter (i.e., `K extends Pick<InterfaceList, T[number]>`) is unconventional and distracting.  Could you try to pare this down to a [mre] with less stuff going on?

Comment: Like, what is `prop` doing?  It doesn't seem to be used anywhere.  And in `isUsingInterfaces` there's no inference site for `K`.  What is `K` doing at all?  Is it just falling back to the constraint?  I'm more than happy to help here but the more I look at this the less I understand what you're doing

Comment: @jcalz prop will be for testing whether the type guard evaluates to true or not,  I am more concerned right now with getting TS to understand what type the input is IF it evaluates to true hence why I omitted showing the test itself

Comment: Edited to try and make it more clear, part of the problem is this I do not think I can get this more minimal. Since the complicated helper types are needed. Let me know if its still confusing.

Comment: If you're not using `prop` in the question, then having it in the question is distracting.  Please make your code a [mre] that doesn't include any code that isn't being used.  I feel like the answer to your original issue is something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgZ5MW), but it doesn't use your particular helper types.  Does that work for you?  If so I can write up an answer for that.  If not, then... please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: "I do not think I can get this more minimal"... I think that's because this might be an XY problem.  You have an actual goal, got partway to that goal using a collection of too-complex typings, and then got stuck.  Maybe you could [edit] the question to ask only about the goal without the potential distractions of partial solutions.

Comment: That intersectprops example seems to be exactly what I was looking for, will poke around and get back

Comment: Completely re-wrote question, and yes, I think the intersectprops approach works wonders! I literally have been googling for over a week and never tripped across that (probably because I didn't know to look up intersectprops)

Comment: Well I'd like to write up my answer but now I'm not exactly seeing how it connects to your question   I'd have expected something like: "let's say I have a type-name-to-type mapping like `interface Mapping { a: {x: string}, b: {y: number}, c: {z: Date} }`. How can I give types to a type guard function that ideally behaves like `if (guard<Mapping>(obj, ["a", "c"])) { obj.x.toUpperCase(), obj.z.getFullYear() }`, and barring that, using currying like `const mappingGuard = guard<Mapping>()` and then `if (mappingGuard(obj, ["a", "c"])) {...}`?"

Comment: The most ideal pipe dream case would look something the effect of `if (guard<A & B>(obj))` but I don't see how that would be possible. I am trying to keep the guard as DRY as possible for the end-user so they don't need to re-write the interface types multiple times every time they use the guard. And again, it needs to actually runtime check since as well.

Comment: Well you can't generate magic run-time type guards from TS types which are erased.  `if (guard<A & B>(obj))` becomes `if (guard(obj))` at runtime.  If you want something that *kind* of works like this you need a different approach, possibly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59483318/2887218).  Is this a duplicate of that question?  I thought this was mostly a type manipulation question: "how do you convert `{a: A, b: B, c: C}` and `"a" | "b"` into `A & B`?"... if this is right I'd be happy to show how `IntersectProps` works and the curried function.  If not, then I'm more lost than ever.

Comment: Yah I understand the TS being erased and why the "ideal" wouldn't actually work. I did see the other answer sometime ago and I am not keen on completely re-writing everything using custom types like `gNumber`, `gString`, since I can just tag the class and check the tag for which interfaces are implemented.  Also not keen on using transformers. 

I left an edit  in the post showing how I used your `Intersectprops`

Comment: I can’t figure out how you want me to answer the question so I think I have to disengage, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think the term "Runtime Guards" is correct, especially the word "Runtime". There are no TypeScript types/type information that persist after transpilation to JavaScript, they are completely erased. Therefore, there are definitely no Runtime type checks related to TypeScript. Intellisense and autocomplete is a design-time matter, a matter of static analysis.

Comment: You say "The runtime check in the type guard is simple, but actually typing the check for intellisense/auto-complete purposes is proving to be tricky." which leading me to think that title "[...] Interface Detection at Runtime" is a typo

Comment: At this point, I am open to suggestions because I can't seem to format these questions in any such way that the good people here at SO can understand. The playground link at the bottom of the post does exactly what I need it to do, thanks to @jcalz

Comment: Ok, I'm reading through the code samples and I'm starting to understand that this is like a function to automatically trigger narrowing (instead of using many discriminators and `if` statements). Interesting +1

Comment: I think that is a correct statement? I don't want to have long winded checks and `if` statements just to say "this thing is using these interfaces"