# Detect object literal being a serialization of a class

Tags: javascript, typescript, instanceof, object-literal

I am looking for a way to detect if an object literal is in fact a "non-instantiated" object of a certain class. I hope it will be more clear with an example:

```
class Range{
    from: number;
    to: number;

    constructor(from: number | Range, to?: number){

        if (from instanceof Range)
            Object.assign(this, from)
        else{
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }
    }

    average(){return (this.to -this.from) / 2;}
}


let one = new Range(1, 20)
let copyOfOne = structuredClone(one);   // This generates an object literal (or kind of ?), the method "average" is not in the prototype
let two = new Range(copyOfOne)          // Constructor won't detect the parmeter as instanceof Range
```

Is there a way to know if an object literal is in fact a "non-instantiated instance" of a certain class? (of course I could check if the object has the class properties, here is simple but with more complex objects would be impractical)

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `structuredClone` ?

Comment: @TobiasS. it's a standard function (recent) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

Comment: You want to know how to detect *at runtime* whether an object matches a certain interface (in this case, the type of a class instance)?  If so then this feels like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59480160/2887218.  If not, could you clarify the difference?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "*non-instantiated instance*". Either it's an object inheriting from the class's prototype object (which we call an instance), or it isn't. If you just want to check whether it's an arbitrary object with `from` and `to` properties, you should check *that*.

Comment: Btw, I recommend `static from(obj) { return new Range(obj.from, obj.to); }` instead of overloading the constructor.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it looks like a duplicate, the answer there is what I was looking for. (Although I don't like adding transformations to ts only for this I got the idea). Thanks.