# Why doesn't Typescript detect that my return value doesn't match my interface?

Tags: typescript

Consider the below code, paying special attention to the `cat` property on the interface:

```
interface Token {
  created: string;
  expires: string;
  id: string;
  lastUsed: string;
  role: string;
  updated: string;
  user: string;
  cat: number;
};

export async function getAuthToken(): Promise<Token | null> {
  try {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');  
    if (!token) {
      return null;
    }
    
    return JSON.parse(token) as Token;
  } catch (error) { return null; }
}
```

Of course, `cat` is not going to be on the actual token, so why doesn't typescript complain that my return value does not match my interface?

Thank you!

Comment: Last i checked, `JSON.parse` returns `any`, plus you even cast to `Token`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Since I cast to Token, shouldn't it detect that 'cat' is not on token? Thanks for the response!

Comment: The first comment is correct but it doesn't look like you're understanding.  There are two problems with your code that prevent type checking.  One is that `JSON.parse()` returns `any`, which disables type checking and pre-dates the existence of the `unknown` type.  See [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24439#issuecomment-400080490); you could use your own definition that makes it `unknown`.

Comment: The second is that you are [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that it is a `Token`.  You are not "casting", at least not in the sense many people mean where there is some runtime coercion.  A type assertion is merely you *telling* the compiler that a value will be `Token` at runtime, so it does not complain.  It's more like a prediction than a conversion (when the weather forecast shows rain for tomorrow, it's not seeding the clouds or anything). If you predict wrong then you are lying to the compiler.

Comment: If I fix both of those I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnbgdN), which gives the desired error.  But you'll find it difficult to get rid of those errors unless you do a very thorough check in the code, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkkKJW) which you might not want to do.

Comment: Do my previous comments fully address your question? If so I can write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz I truly appreciate your help! Your example gives the error `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Token | null'`. My idea of the desired error would be something like `Property 'cat' does not exist on 'token'`, or something, which I feel like I've seen before. Your error also goes away if I assert (thank you for the correction) it as type `Token`. Is what I'm aiming for just not possible in the case of `JSON.parse` because we won't know what is on token until runtime? Thank you!

Comment: It's not possible in the case of *any* TypeScript warning.  TypeScript is a compiler that produces JavaScript, and any compiler warnings have to be issued well before runtime.  There's no actual value named `token` to look at when the compiler has to decide if what you're doing is safe or not.  It will warn if it thinks your code is probably in error, but it's not actually *running* the code.

Comment: @jcalz Okay. Last question, would you recommend keeping the assertion for readability even though it doesn't really do anything, or is it redundant?

Comment: I would lean toward `return JSON.parse(token) as Token` as being more indicative of your intent than relying on the function return type annotation, but either way is fine, really.  Feels opinion-y and not anything with an authoritative answer.  But now we're drifting away from the scope of this question as asked.

Comment: My intent with these comments is to figure out what answer, if any, to post. If I post something like "The compiler has no idea what `JSON.parse(token)` will produce; the default is `any` which is permissive, and `as Token` is an assertion, not a runtime cast" would that answer your question, or does it miss it somehow?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that would answer it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler doesn't know anything about `token` other than the fact that it's going to be some `string` at runtime.  And even if somehow knew the exact [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) that `token` would be, the [standard library typing for the `JSON.parse()` method](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4f54e7e947298162d29f3104265e74dcfbc90d82/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1126) doesn't attempt to figure out what the shape of the returned value would be.  Instead, it just returns [the unsafe `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any):

```
declare var JSON: JSON;
interface JSON {
    parse(text: string, reviver?: (this: any, key: string, value: any) => any): any;
}
```

The `any` type is an "escape hatch" for the type system and essentially turns off type checking.  So in `const ret = JSON.parse(token)`, `ret` is of type `any`, and suddenly any crazy thing is permitted:

```
const ret: any = JSON.parse(token);
ret.cat.toUpperCase(); // no error
ret.dog.bark(); // no error
ret.cat.bat.rat.gnat.wombat.muskrat.meerkat.polecat.goat.stoat.meat; // no error
```

This isn't great, but that's the way it is.  There's not much point trying to make the return type depend on the literal type of the input, since that would be *very* complicated and mostly useless, since the TypeScript compiler checks code *well before runtime* and so will almost never know very much about the input value.

There is also no built-in `json` type corresponding to just valid `JSON.parse()` outputs, although there's a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#1897](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897) asking for this.

It would be safer if `JSON.parse()` returned [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) instead of `any`, but the typings for `JSON.parse()` pre-dates [the introduction of the safer `unknown` type in TypeScript 3.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type)... and changing it now would be a [large breaking change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24439#issuecomment-400080490).

If you have a safer alternative for the `JSON.parse()` call signature that you want to use instead, you can [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) it in yourself.  For example:

```
// merge it in
interface JSON {
  parse(x: string): unknown; 
}
```

Now you would get a compiler error if you return `JSON.parse(token)` directly:

```
async function getAuthToken(): Promise<Token | null> {
  try {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    if (!token) {  return null;  }
    const ret = JSON.parse(token);
    return ret; // error!  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Token | null'
  } catch (error) { return null; }
}
```

---

Note that even without the `any` type, you can still suppress compiler errors by using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
async function getAssertAuthToken(): Promise<Token | null> {
  try {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    if (!token) { return null; }
    const ret = JSON.parse(token);
    return ret as Token; // okay
  } catch (error) { return null; }
}
```

That's because TypeScript has *assertions*, not "cast"s... or at least the term "cast" is ambiguous enough to be confusing.  A type assertion is like a "static cast" and just tells the compiler that it's okay to treat a value as having a particular type.  Think of it as you giving the compiler information that it doesn't have.  If you think the result of `JSON.parse(token)` will be a valid `Token` but the compiler doesn't know this, then you can write `JSON.parse(token) as Token` to tell it so.  It is absolutely not a "runtime cast" that performs any kind of coercion at runtime.  TypeScript's type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) from the emitted JavaScript, so any runtime coercion needs to involve JavaScript code.  You can write `String(x)` to turn `x` into a `string` at runtime (and the compiler understands this) but `x as string` has no such effect; it's a *prediction*, not an *operation*.

---

So, if you don't use a type assertion and you don't use `any`, you will probably be in the position where the compiler complains that it can't be sure that the value is really a `Token`.  At this point the only way forward would be to perform a thorough runtime check of the output in a way that the compiler understands to be [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) from `unknown` all the way down to `Token`:

```
function hasPropOfType<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey, V>(
  obj: T, key: K, valGuard: (x: any) => x is V): obj is T & Record<K, V> {
  return valGuard((obj as any)[key]);
}
function isString(x: any): x is string { return typeof x === "string" };
function isNumber(x: any): x is number { return typeof x === "number" };
async function getAuthToken(): Promise<Token | null> {
  try {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    if (!token) {
      return null;
    }
    const ret = JSON.parse(token);
    if (!ret) return null;
    if (typeof ret !== "object") return null;
    if (!hasPropOfType(ret, "created", isString)) return null;
    if (!hasPropOfType(ret, "expires", isString)) return null;
    if (!hasPropOfType(ret, "id", isString)) return null;
    if (!hasPropOfType(ret, "lastUsed", isString)) return null;
    if (!hasPropOfType(ret, "role", isString)) return null;
    if (!hasPropOfType(ret, "updated", isString)) return null;
    if (!hasPropOfType(ret, "user", isString)) return null;
    if (!hasPropOfType(ret, "cat", isNumber)) return null;
    return ret; // okay
  } catch (error) { return null; }
}
```

Here we've written some [custom type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) and used them a bunch of times until the compiler is convinced on its own that `ret` is of type `Token`.  If you're interested in this sort of approach, you might want to look at [Typescript check object by type or interface at runtime with typeguards in 2020+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480160/typescript-check-object-by-type-or-interface-at-runtime-with-typeguards-in-2020)

---

So, there you go. TypeScript doesn't complain that `cat` doesn't exist on `JSON.parse(token) as Token` because:

- it doesn't know anything about `token` other than it's a `string`
- `JSON.parse()`'s return type is `any`, which makes the compiler accept any crazy thing
- even if you make it return something safer like `unknown`, the type assertion `as Token` serves to *suppress* errors, not generate them

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#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-AAK3CMAABpkAAaXsxzqCXCzoDAJIfIgJJvIANSdMpJBc1z6FQbzsCSegfO8gA3OAlAAcXMVYZB5INRmLcYXR4RdkCivkEqq1BkAAMmQAAlcIsmoS0MuqlC9AedjsrygqoGoMoyjq6SRiSaoAG1UoAXU7D8jIVJVcAtDJ7GKqa+Uqi1ZHsEt+t7UKp3QHNKvGK7kG2HRxG2LoFBWkzF3mXwAigbbSvoPal28fxoCOp8ToPc7kEu67tn+j6HpCb9pT-Yy1pVUDtT1XDIOg80rSPJDON6t0oA9BjeL9XDAwIsMEmIqMyNjeNSk2Gi6M7TDgBzfN23vBjxOOl83wYj9MNJx8BIWZZhO5LmxMY-NBmLbTKxl9nc1OiAwcbPNIYSjztgVvmdKrBiVfzMyGAsqybO5QZvO2chKBobZvI2kxWGqfXgf5o2uxNvMzYt6yDzKG2bt4AQhCdxdNrYd22N7JXjY5v3zP0SzA6nYOHlt6RI5d+xY8VzjlaT-3U8toOQ+2FR1E0ahc4YaOag99iE59kuU-QNOrczrybv0Qx68bt3m-jovE6Y0vO-LjPK8saxHedhvXYLg3W7Z9vzbL9Prazm6aMH5eR694uJ47ruK93u2qHrt6AagFfPcNmXtMGOTkAUpTFHPW41LKW976Bi3IuelxRAA)