# parse text into specific type?

Tags: json, typescript

how can i parse a fetched text file into a specific Type?

i currently do something like this:

```
const cjsons = fetched
    .split('\n')
    .filter(line => line.startsWith('{'))
    .map(string => JSON.parse(string)) as CityJSON[]
```

where fetched is a textfile where every line is a new json. i know that `as ...` will force the type onto the result.
it works. but i am afraid that in the moment the source file does not fit on the CityJSON type i run into Problems. Is there a way to test wether `fetched` does actually fit into the CityJSON type?

Comment: You can try with [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), where your guard checks if all properties exist and have the existed type. Then you can call it and if it returns false handle the error. If it returns true typescript will assert it as CityJSON type

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of [Typescript check object by type or interface at runtime with typeguards in 2020+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59480160/2887218) unless I'm missing something about the question

Comment: Hi there, indeed, it does cover my question. Sorry for overseeing this. 
I am now using https://github.com/colinhacks/zod to do my typechecking. Works wonderfully.