# babel typescript interface convert to variable

Tags: typescript, babeljs, typescript-compiler-api, ts-morph

There is `Props` interface from third-party:

```js
interface Props {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  approval: Approval
}

interface Approval {
  signature: string;
}
```

What is the solution that `Props` convert to array:

```js
[
  {
    name: 'id',
    type: 'string'
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
    type:'string'
  },
  {
    name: 'age',
    type: 'number'
  },
  {
    name: 'approval',
    type: 'Approval'
  }
]
```

I have no idea that Typescript's interface can do this?

Update: Maybe it is not 'convert', somehow it just like 'reflect' or something else. Can I do this in babel?

However, I just want to get this array by `Props`.

Comment: Convert to a type or convert to a value?

Comment: Interfaces are part of the type system. They only exist during compilation for the compiler to check validity of code. They do not exist after compilation. It's not clear what or how you want to convert. Although, I'd note that the array doesn't have valid `Props` items, since they are all missing the mandatory attributes `age` and `approval`.

Comment: @VLAZ yes. Maybe it is not convert, I think it just like 'reflect' ? I know Golang can do this, but I don't know how to do in Typescript.

Comment: You can't do this; as VLAZ said, TypeScript's type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) upon compilation to JavaScript.  Nothing of `Props` or `Approval` will exist at runtime for you to turn into an array. There is no reflection in TypeScript.  You can either add a build step to do reflection, or you can refactor to write your array and generate types from it.  The various options are described in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59480160/2887218). Does that fully address the question, or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I solved this problem through TS Compile API:

```
const {Project, SyntaxKind, Node, PropertySignature} = require('ts-morph');
const {resolve, dirname} = require('path');

    let res = {
        "Msg": [{
            "type": "string",
            "name": "type"
        }]
    }
    const project = new Project()
    project.addSourceFileAtPath(sourceFilePath)
    const sourceFile = project.getSourceFile(sourceFilePath)

    const msgInterfaces = sourceFile.getInterfaces()
        .filter((interfaceDecl) => {
            const interfaceName = interfaceDecl.getName()
            return interfaceName.endsWith("SDKType") && !interfaceName.includes("Response")
        })

    for (const msgInterface of msgInterfaces) {
        console.log(sourceFilePath, msgInterface.getName(), 'is building')

        const properties = msgInterface.getProperties()

        for (const property of properties) {
            const propStructure = property.getStructure()

            let name = propStructure.name
            let type = propStructure.type;

            if (BASIC_MSG_EIP712_TYPES[type]) {
                res["Msg"].push({
                    type: BASIC_MSG_EIP712_TYPES[type],
                    name,
                })
                continue
            }

            if (property.getType().isEnum()) {
                type = "string"
                res["Msg"].push({
                    type,
                    name,
                })
                continue;
            }

            if (property.getType().isArray()) {
                const ele = property.getType().getArrayElementType().getText()
                if (!Object.keys(BASIC_MSG_EIP712_TYPES).includes(ele)) continue;

                type = BASIC_MSG_EIP712_TYPES[ele] + "[]"
                res["Msg"].push({
                    type,
                    name
                })
                continue
            }

            if (property.getType().getSymbol().getDeclarations()[0].getKind() === SyntaxKind.InterfaceDeclaration) {
                type = "Type" + upperCaseFirst(snakeToCamel(name))
                res["Msg"].push({
                    type,
                    name,
                })

                const pps = property.getType().getProperties()
                res[type] = pps.map(p => {
                    return {
                        type: p.getValueDeclaration().getType().getText(),
                        name: p.getName(),
                    }
                })
                continue;
            }
        }

        project.createSourceFile(
            `./${dirname(filePath)}/${msgInterface.getName()}EIP712.ts`,
            `export const ${msgInterface.getName()}EIP712 = ${JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)} \n\n`,
            {overwrite: true}
        )
        project.saveSync()
    }
```